# What is it called when single letters are used as words in a sentence?

Tags: single-word-requests

What is it called when single letters are used as words in a sentence?

> I C A B.
>   I C D B P!
>
> I see a Bee.
>   I see the bee pee!

> F U N-E X?
>   S I F X.
>   F U N-E M?
>   S I F M.
>   OK I L F M N X!
>
> Have you any eggs?
>   Yes I have eggs.
>   Have you any Ham?
>   Yes I have ham.
>   OK. I will have ham and eggs.

I have been looking for this, at a low level, for years.

Comment: Capital offences.

Comment: The Two Ronnies did a sketch comprising just this sort of language about twenty years ago, possibly longer.

Comment: [A B C D Goldfish? L M N No Goldfish. C M P N?](http://cheezburger.com/2118019840) I can has cheezeburger?

Comment: Andrew - amazing I remember that clearly

Comment: [SMS Language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SMS_language) in general but it is not about using single letters only.

Comment: If the **B** mt put: If the **B**.

Comment: @AndrewLeach, I just looked it up, it was more than 40 years before this question was asked!  It was titled: Swedish Made Simple.

Answer (score 5):

I do like *acronymation* for the proliferation of acronyms in new media. But I think the examples given in the question (and some comments) are either humorous or puzzles.

In such cases, the word **rebus** would apply:

> a riddle or puzzle made up of letters, pictures, or symbols whose
>   names sound like the parts or syllables of a word or phrase. *Merriam
>   Webster*

Comment: Right! Wikipedia says: "Some tokens of the SMS language can be likened to a rebus, using pictures and single letters or numbers to represent whole words" under [SMS language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SMS_language) article.

Comment: Rebus is fine, but here it is not a question of word puzzles, it is a communication issue.

Answer (score 1):

This is a [reverse mondegreen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mondegreen%23Reverse_mondegreen) -- where words appear to be nonsense, but sound sensible when spoken aloud.

Comment: I'm not sure that a mondegreen is nonsense in either of its forms, though. It's a mis-hearing of a lyric, or other spoken text, but the "wrong" version is usually coherent: "The girl with colitis goes by", or "Dining Out in Paris and London".

Comment: The examples under "reverse mondegreen" on Wikipedia are pretty nonsensical when not spoken aloud, I think, although they might have gotten the definition wrong. I definitely agree that this **is** a rebus; I just think RM better captures the seeming nonsensicalness and the solution of the puzzle (to speak it out).

Comment: Yep, you have a point!

Comment: @Margana, which song does the "Dining Out..." come from?  Also, would you consider "Mairzy Doats" to be the correct or the wrong interpretation?  XD